# An HTML picture src is showing on my live site but not local or in my code

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, digital-ocean

I deployed a website recently and on my live website I see the following html:

```
<img id="profilePicture" src="profile_stock_avatar.png" alt="profilePicture">
```

This src is nowhere else to be found. On the handlebars code I have for the page it is:

```
<img id="profilePicture" src="{{picture}}" alt="profilePicture"/>
```

With {{picture}} being a link to a picture of the earth, definitely not profile_stock_avatar, which is what I used a long time ago for the page. When I run the site locally, it doesn't have that stock avatar at all, it has the earth one. This only shows on the live sit, even after pulling the git repo. My server code for loading the page is:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).render('body', notePostData['welcome']);
});
```

with the notePostData of 'welcome' being:

```
"welcome" : {
    "picture" : "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2422/sky-earth-galaxy-universe.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
    "username" : "Welcome!",
    "biography" : "Creating an account is coming soon :) In the meantime, feel free to leave a note!",
    "posts" : [
          {
          }
    ]
}
```

I have been pulling my teeth out trying to find out what is going on. Please help me!

Comment: Hi, could you paste the link to your website here so I can inspect myself? Got an idea, just need to check it out first :)

Comment: Hey buddy, thank you so much for your help! Apparently I just needed to 'sudo reboot' my server! I should have updated this post but again, thank you!

Comment: Sure, exactly what I was going to suggest :)